# How to test connection string?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a simple issue, I am trying to check if the connection string in `App.config` is valid and the server & database inside of it are accessible. I have tried the following code but still it doesn't work:-

```
public static bool checkConnectionString(string con)
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con].ConnectionString == "" && !checkConnectionStringValidity(con))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static bool checkConnectionStringValidity(string con)
{
   try {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(con)) {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then I use the above methods in the main screen:-

```
if (Data.checkConnectionString("Utilities"))
{
    Application.Run(new Log_In());
}
else 
{
    Application.Run(new ApplicationMainSettings());  
}
```

I want that when I write wrong information in the `app.config` the program directs me to `ApplicationMainSettings()` screen.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass in the actual connection string? `... !checkConnectionStringValidity(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con].ConnectionString))`

Comment: Your call to checkConnectionStringValidity doesn't pass the actual connection string.

Comment: It seems you haven't debugged it before asking. You just parsed the string from the method, not from the App.config. Edit: Patrick and Simon already pointed this out

Comment: Yes I was wrong but, when I passed the real connection string nothing happens ...!

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks fine and working, the issue is `&&` operator in the if, Due to its presents the method `checkConnectionStringValidity` will called only if the connection string  is `""` I thing it is not needed to check for `""` here you can directly use like the following:

```
if(checkConnectionStringValidity(ConfigurationManager.Connecti‌​onStrings[con].Conne‌​ctionString))
{
    // Proceed the connection is valid
}
else
{
    // Stop here the connection is invalid
}
```

Or else you can try  with `!= "" && checkConnectionStringValidity(con)` so the method will called only if the connection string is non-empty(because, the method will definitely return false if the value is empty). So you can try like this:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con].ConnectionString != "" && checkConnectionStringValidity(con))
{
    // Proceed the connection is valid
}
else
{
    // Stop here the connection is invalid
}
```

Comment: Or change the && in a ||

Comment: @Steve: that too fine but not necessary, If it is empty means the method will return `false`.  I have updated the post\

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the code to apply the intended logic...

```
public static bool checkConnectionString(string key) {
    var connectionSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key];
    return connectionSetting != null && checkConnectionStringValidity(connectionSetting.ConnectionString);
}
```

We first check that the connect settings actually exist.

If it does then you can check the connection string.

If it does not then you run the chance of getting a null exception.

Comment: @Medo I saw where I made the mistake. Used the wrong method. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

```
public static bool checkConnectionStringValidity(string con)
{
var _testConnection=false;
try {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(con)) {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            _testConnection = true;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
} catch {
    _testConnection = false;
}
return _testConnection ;
```

}

also you need to change checkConnectionString function as per below.

```
public static bool checkConnectionString(string con)
{
if(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con] !=null)
{
  if (Convert.Tostring( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con].ConnectionString) == "" && !checkConnectionStringValidity(con)
  { 
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
     return true;
  }
}
else 
{
     return false;
}
}
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Please share details in which function you get return false?